# Android Sip Client registering successfully but failing to make outgoing call

Tags: android, sip, voip, freeswitch

I am trying to make a call via my custom sip client. I am being able to register my SIP profile successfully and am receiving incoming calls successfully too but while making outgoing calls am facing problems.

In the logcat I getting the following error:

sip errorcode -6

```
com.android.server.sip.SipSession Group$Make CallCommand
```

while the following is the siptrace of freeswitch:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:9198@10.129.28.241 SIP/2.0
   Call-ID: ecfe2bbb0c4be0ca556d4f69c4d29188@10.129.28.75
   CSeq: 5490 INVITE
   From: <sip:1019@10.129.28.241>;tag=3095854940
   To: <sip:9198@10.129.28.241>
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.129.28.75:47642;branch=z9hG4bKa80387f35fdf1701b2cb37f1de0c3edb353031;rport
   Max-Forwards: 70
   Contact: <sip:1019@10.129.28.75:47642;transport=udp>
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Length: 297

   v=0
   o=- 1389522189651 1389522189669 IN IP4 10.129.28.75
   s=-
   c=IN IP4 10.129.28.75
   t=0 0
   m=audio 33590 RTP/AVP 96 97 3 0 8 127
   a=rtpmap:96 GSM-EFR/8000
   a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000
   a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
   a=rtpmap:127 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:127 0-15
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 374 bytes to udp/[10.129.28.75]:47642 at 10:23:21.404790:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 100 Trying
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.129.28.75:47642;branch=z9hG4bKa80387f35fdf1701b2cb37f1de0c3edb353031;rport=47642
   From: <sip:1019@10.129.28.241>;tag=3095854940
   To: <sip:9198@10.129.28.241>
   Call-ID: ecfe2bbb0c4be0ca556d4f69c4d29188@10.129.28.75
   CSeq: 5490 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.8b+git~20140103T212148Z~ae7371e7c5~64bit
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-01-12 15:53:21.402024 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1055 New Channel sofia/internal/1019@10.129.28.241 [8fba409c-7b73-11e3-bc5c-b3f2a23fd7a2]
send 892 bytes to udp/[10.129.28.75]:47642 at 10:23:21.406530:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.129.28.75:47642;branch=z9hG4bKa80387f35fdf1701b2cb37f1de0c3edb353031;rport=47642
   From: <sip:1019@10.129.28.241>;tag=3095854940
   To: <sip:9198@10.129.28.241>;tag=67DrgHp353eFa
   Call-ID: ecfe2bbb0c4be0ca556d4f69c4d29188@10.129.28.75
   CSeq: 5490 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.8b+git~20140103T212148Z~ae7371e7c5~64bit
   Accept: application/sdp
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, precondition, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="10.129.28.241", nonce="8fba5b68-7b73-11e3-bc5d-b3f2a23fd7a2", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 892 bytes to udp/[10.129.28.75]:47642 at 10:23:21.907617:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.129.28.75:47642;branch=z9hG4bKa80387f35fdf1701b2cb37f1de0c3edb353031;rport=47642
   From: <sip:1019@10.129.28.241>;tag=3095854940
   To: <sip:9198@10.129.28.241>;tag=67DrgHp353eFa
   Call-ID: ecfe2bbb0c4be0ca556d4f69c4d29188@10.129.28.75
   CSeq: 5490 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.8b+git~20140103T212148Z~ae7371e7c5~64bit
   Accept: application/sdp
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, precondition, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="10.129.28.241", nonce="8fba5b68-7b73-11e3-bc5d-b3f2a23fd7a2", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 892 bytes to udp/[10.129.28.75]:47642 at 10:23:22.907607:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.129.28.75:47642;branch=z9hG4bKa80387f35fdf1701b2cb37f1de0c3edb353031;rport=47642
   From: <sip:1019@10.129.28.241>;tag=3095854940
   To: <sip:9198@10.129.28.241>;tag=67DrgHp353eFa
   Call-ID: ecfe2bbb0c4be0ca556d4f69c4d29188@10.129.28.75
   CSeq: 5490 INVITE
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.5.8b+git~20140103T212148Z~ae7371e7c5~64bit
   Accept: application/sdp
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, precondition, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="10.129.28.241", nonce="8fba5b68-7b73-11e3-bc5d-b3f2a23fd7a2", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------

freeswitch@VPCEH36EN> sofia global siptrace off

+OK Global siptrace off
freeswitch@VPCEH36EN> 2014-01-12 15:53:31.442026 [WARNING] switch_core_state_machine.c:567 8fba409c-7b73-11e3-bc5c-b3f2a23fd7a2 sofia/internal/1019@10.129.28.241 Abandoned
2014-01-12 15:53:31.442026 [NOTICE] switch_core_state_machine.c:570 Hangup sofia/internal/1019@10.129.28.241 [CS_NEW] [WRONG_CALL_STATE]
2014-01-12 15:53:31.442026 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1609 Session 10 (sofia/internal/1019@10.129.28.241) Ended
2014-01-12 15:53:31.442026 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1613 Close Channel sofia/internal/1019@10.129.28.241 [CS_DESTROY]
```

Answer (score 0):

The SIP proxy requires authentication (status "407 proxy authentication required" and Proxy-Authenticate header) but you don't send any (no Proxy-Authorization header). Usually you need to use the same credentials you used for registration also for creating a call.